# nerual network: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I try to use tensorboard when training the nn, but the problem appear:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: {{function_node _*wrapped__CreateSummaryFileWriter_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} C:\Users\use\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4z3qcdpm is not a directory [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs
import tensorflow_docs.modeling
import tensorflow_docs.plots
from  IPython import display
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import pathlib
import shutil
import tempfile

logdir = pathlib.Path(tempfile.mkdtemp())/"tensorboard_logs"
shutil.rmtree(logdir, ignore_errors=True)
FEATURES = 28
gz = tf.keras.utils.get_file('HIGGS.csv.gz', 'http://mlphysics.ics.uci.edu/data/higgs/HIGGS.csv.gz')
ds = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(gz,[float(),]*(FEATURES+1), compression_type="GZIP")

def pack_row(*row):
  label = row[0]
  features = tf.stack(row[1:],1)
  return features, label

packed_ds = ds.batch(10000).map(pack_row).unbatch()

for features,label in packed_ds.batch(1000).take(1):
  print(features[0])
  plt.hist(features.numpy().flatten(), bins = 101)

N_VALIDATION = int(1e3)
N_TRAIN = int(1e4)
BUFFER_SIZE = int(1e4)
BATCH_SIZE = 500
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = N_TRAIN//BATCH_SIZE

validate_ds = packed_ds.take(N_VALIDATION).cache()
train_ds = packed_ds.skip(N_VALIDATION).take(N_TRAIN).cache()

validate_ds = validate_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.InverseTimeDecay(
  0.001,
  decay_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH*1000,
  decay_rate=1,
  staircase=False)

def get_optimizer():
  return tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_schedule)

step = np.linspace(0,100000)
lr = lr_schedule(step)
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
plt.plot(step/STEPS_PER_EPOCH, lr)
plt.ylim([0,max(plt.ylim())])
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
_ = plt.ylabel('Learning Rate')

def get_callbacks(name):
  return [
    tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots(),
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_binary_crossentropy', patience=200),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir/name),
  ]

def compile_and_fit(model, name, optimizer=None, max_epochs=10000):
  if optimizer is None:
    optimizer = get_optimizer()
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=[
                  tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
                      from_logits=True, name='binary_crossentropy'),
                  'accuracy'])

  model.summary()

  history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
    epochs=max_epochs,
    validation_data=validate_ds,
    callbacks=get_callbacks(name),
    verbose=0)
  return history


tiny_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(16, activation='elu', input_shape=(FEATURES,)),
    layers.Dense(1)
])

size_histories = {}

size_histories['Tiny'] = compile_and_fit(tiny_model, 'sizes/Tiny')

plotter = tfdocs.plots.HistoryPlotter(metric = 'binary_crossentropy', smoothing_std=10)
plotter.plot(size_histories)
plt.ylim([0.5, 0.7])
```

I try to normalize the code, making sure there is no space or other things in the dir, but it doesn't work.